# WCF, entity framework and impersonation

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, wcf

I'm developing a WCF service who use windows authentication to validate client credentials.

Using this binding it works pretty fine

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding>          
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

With the following service method :

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]    
public class PricesSynchro : IPricesSynchro
{

    [OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Required)]
    public string Hello()
    {
        return "Hello " + OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Name;            
    }
```

But now I would use entity framework with trusted connection using these credentials and it doesn't work.
I tried to impersonate using the following code :

```
using(OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate())
{
}
```

Where did I fail ? I'm banging my head on the wall since 8 hours...
Thanks by advance.

Comment: When you are testing is your WCF client and WCF server on the same physical machine or on different computers ?

Comment: Also, is you database server on a different computer than the WCF server ?

Comment: I use WCF test client and a remote database server

Comment: So yeah same machine host client and server

Answer (score 0):

Your process is probably not authorized to delegate its impersonation to another server. As documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730088(v=vs.110).aspx) :

> When the impersonation level is Impersonation, the front-end and back-end services must be running on the same machine. When the impersonation level is Delegation, the front-end and back-end services can be on separate machines or on the same machine. Enabling delegation-level impersonation requires that Windows domain policy be configured to permit delegation.

Most likely your admins do not have the Delegation domain policy turned on.